# Rails will_paginate custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

How can I use will_paginate with a custom route?

I have the following in my routes:

```
map.connect 'human-readable/:name', :controller => :tags, :action => 'show'
```

but will_paginate uses url_for as far as I can tell, but I want to use 'human-readable' instead of url_for, but how?

**Edit**

When I click the paging link generated by `will_paginate`, it's using:

```
"tags/show?name=Elektronikindustri&page=1"
```

Instead of:

```
"/human-readable/show?name=Elektronikindustri&page=1"
```

I want `will_paginate` to use my custom route instead of the actual controller name

Comment: When I click the paging link generated by will_paginate it's using tags/show?name=Elektronikindustri&page=1 and not '/human-readable/show?name=Elektronikindustri&page=1' - how can I change this?

'human-readable' is inside my routes file like this:
map.connect 'human-readable/:name', :controller => :tags, :action => 'show'

I want will_paginate to use my custom route instead of the actual controller name

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `will_paginate` view helper has a `:params` option for overriding the default link generation.

Change your routes configuration:

```
map.human_readable_tag '/human-readable/:name', 
     :controller => :tags, :action => 'show'
```

Invoke the `will_paginate` view helper as follows:

```
<%= will_paginate @tag_list, 
     :params => {:controller => human_readable_tag_path(@tag_name) } %>
```

Make sure you have set the `@tag_name` variable in your controller.

For more information read the [`will_paginate` view helper documentation](http://gitrdoc.com/rdoc/mislav/will_paginate/b3b0f593ea9b1da13a64bc825dfe17b6bbc2828b/classes/WillPaginate/ViewHelpers.html#M000134).

The `:params` option passed to the helper is used to invoke `url_for`. So read the `url_for` [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000649) for how we faked a controller name.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use param in will_paginate but passing in the parameter like so:

```
<%= will_paginate @products, :params => {:controller => 'human-readable', :action => 'show', :name => 'xyz'} %>
```

and now your links will look like human-readable/xyz?page=2...

Answer (score 0):

You need define this route too

```
map.connect 'human-readable/:name', :controller => :tags, :action => 'show'
map.connect 'human-readable/:name/page/:page', :controller => :tags, :action => 'show'
```

Comment: Great thank you, how do I get will_paginate to pick this one up? It's still using 'tags'? When I click a link in the pagination it's still using 'tags' and not 'human-readable'