# will_paginate not using current route

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

We're using will_paginate to display associations of a model. We have some custom routes set up like so:

```
get '/profile/:slug' => 'talents#show', :as => :talent
get '/profile/:slug/bio' => 'talents#show', :as => :talent_bio
get '/profile/:slug/instagram' => 'talents#show', :as => :talent_instagram
```

When we're using talent_instagram route, all pagination links are rendered to the default route instead. That is, instead of:

```
http:://0.0.0.0:3000/profile/some-talent/instagram?page=5
```

This is what we get:

```
http:://0.0.0.0:3000/profile/some-talent?page=5
```

If I comment out the first two routes, then the correct link is used. Why is will_paginate defaulting to the first route?

Comment: have you tried flipping the order of those routes. i.e. first to last, last to first?

Comment: yep that what I ended up doing - just changing the order of the routes - make this an answer and I'll mark it correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of the routes to

```
get '/profile/:slug/instagram' => 'talents#show', :as => :talent_instagram
get '/profile/:slug/bio' => 'talents#show', :as => :talent_bio
get '/profile/:slug' => 'talents#show', :as => :talent
```

because routes are matched in the order they are specified!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct answer or not, but this may help you [Rails will_paginate custom route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441643/rails-will-paginate-custom-route)

Comment: Yeah I checked this out, its for Rails 2. Still I thought it could help me but no luck