# Get the actual id of current user without deleting the session? rails will_paginate dilema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, will-paginate

I want to get the real id of a User due to a problem in the url for will_paginate in that I need to set it manually, so I want to get the target link for will paginate by a custom renderer method in the view like this,

```
<%= will_paginate @friends, :renderer => WillPaginateHelper::MyLinkRenderer %>
```

And the helper is something like,

```
module WillPaginateHelper

  class MyLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::ActionView::LinkRenderer
    include SessionsHelper
    protected

    def link(text, target, attributes = {})
      if target.is_a?(Integer)
        attributes[:rel] = rel_value(target)
        target = "/users" + current_user.id + "/friends?page=#{target}"
      end
      attributes[:href] = target
      tag(:a, text, attributes)
    end
  end
end
```

The line `target = "/users" + current_user.id + "/friends?page=#{target}"` is the important one where I need to set the url for will_paginate anchor links with the current user id.

Problem is that when the helper I am using is ran in the view to set the url, I get a error `undefined local variable or method session...`, you cannot use sessions hash in helpers so how to get the real id of the current_user to insert into variable. Do I delete/destroy the session get the id and create a new one? The problem is once I delete the session how to get the id once I delete the session and the user reference is deleted.

**Reason**
I have a friends#index action that is rendered in a div and upon initial call to url the pagination attaches correctly being the url `users/:id/friends` so each pagination request goes to the correct user and action. But this index view has "Unfriend" form attached to each displayed friend so you can destroy the friendship which goes to the destroy action of the friends controller so markup is eg `<form... action="friends/177"...>` and on full view reload of the index action from destroy action will paginate attaches to the last known link unless overriden. So when index action is fully rendered again pagination links are `friends/177` which give a server error anyway and makes no sense as that record just got destroyed.

I have the current_user variables and id in my destroy action but I can not find a way to get them to my helper method, or simply get the current user id from the session.

Comment: You're missing a slash. `"/users/" + current_user.id + "/friends?page=#{target}"`. But you should just use the link helper generated by your routes instead.

Comment: ahh thnx. i tried and looked at many examples on using params option using the route eg `params: { controller: user_friends_path(@friends)...}` but couldnt generate route like that with any of the options for that, some peoples faked the route with url_for docs but I couldnt do that.

Comment: And the statement "you cannot use sessions hash in helpers" is completely false. Helpers are included into the view context so they can access anything the controller can.

Comment: well it seems you cant.

Comment: No, you have screwed something up. Maybe you removed the sessions middleware.

Comment: Try generating a new rails app if you don't belive me but its definatly false. I'm going to go out on a limb and say you should not be reinventing the authentication wheel. Stick with something tried like Devise,

Comment: Other people had the same issue trying to do something similar eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774257/access-session-in-helper-file-rails-3) apparently they are only available to controllers and not the model etc. I do not have time to create a new app right now.

Comment: That answer is for Rails 3.

Comment: Thing is I tested this, so you can include the session hash with `include SessionsHelper` in the WillPaginateHelper and it will include the `current_user` method in sessions helper but you get the sessions error. thats all I can really say about that i am pretty sure my code is right in rails 5 I followed the MH tutorial, not devise, so iam not 100% but rails generates the error anyway.

Comment: The problem here is that what you are creating is not a helper. Helpers are modules that are included into the view context. Its a class that extends `WillPaginate::ActionView::LinkRenderer`. If you want to give it access the session you have to pass it in via arguments.

Comment: Yes you are right, do you know how to go about it so it acts like a normal helper? Sorry this is pushing my limits atm of understanding.

Comment: You want to search for how to paginate nested resources with will_paginate instead as you're most likely making it much more complicated than needed. I havent used it but you will want something like `will_paginate current_user.friends` and make sure you have declared the route like in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: Yes I searched and most people who wanted to change the url went for this, you can make the controller option in params work but I do not think you can get nested results from that. If you want we can move this to discussion quickly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158479/discussion-between-lee-eather-and-max).

Comment: so did you do the nested resources? also isn't just easy to set an if condition in the view to avoid that error? `So when index action is fully rendered again pagination links are friends/177 which give a server error anyway and makes no sense as that record just got destroyed.`

Comment: Hi, nested resource I cant figure yet.  I was thinking of using [here](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/action_view.rb) url_for as people said it was what will_paginate method used, the same options only just looking now. If condition still doesnt get me a url?

Comment: [rails sessions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) so I can get the current_user session id displayed in the view but say in the helper modules I cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to max and everyone for helping me.  found this post and this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441643/rails-will-paginate-custom-route#answer-6133947) which you can do something like,

In your routes

```
get 'users/:cu_id/friends', to: 'users#index', as: :my_friends
```

And for the view

```
<%= will_paginate @friends, params: { controller: :users, :cu_id => current_user.id } %>
```

This will produce `users/:cu_id/friends?page=2`... of course :cu_id will be the actual id number, for pagination.

**EDIT:** Order is important here to if you have any other routes going to the same url eg, `users/:user_id/friends` when you nest resources, you need to put `get 'users/:cu_id/friends',...` below this, as rails will build the correct route for you for will paginate but come back in through the friends#index action when paginated and match eg `users/1/friends` through `users/:user_id/friends` as it is first in order in routes.rb. [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#static-segments) in rails guide it explains how it works.